# While trying to integrate Ms crm 2015 online to ms Outlook I get an error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

While trying top integrate my outlook with my online crm 2015 I am getting this error:

> There is a problem communicating with the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server. The server might be unavailable. Try again later. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post on the CRM Community forum [here](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/120666.aspx).

Try uninstalling the plugin profiler.

Comment: Hi! Try not to just add links to other forums that can possibly contain answers, but rather try to include the answers inside your posts!

Comment: Sorry I am eager to get involved. The answer is uninstall the plugin profiler. The link is sighting my references like the document on submitting good posts recommends. I will keep this in mind. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

[The link says this >>](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/120666.aspx)

> so, I got to the bottom of it (sort of). I ended up looking at the SDF
>   files on my local client and taking the following steps:
>
> 1) I dropped the constraint on EntityClientStatistics on the SDF file.
>   (yes, I know this is unsupported, but bear with me).
>
> 2) I re-ran the configuration.
>
> 3) Once completed, I queried the EntityClientStatistics table looking
>   for the duplicate entity id that was causing my problem.
>
> 4) once I found that EntityID, I went to my Organization database on
>   my CRM Database Server and found the entity that was causing the
>   issue. for some reason that entity had duplicated versions of its
>   forms.
>
> 5) I deleted that entity and recreated it.
>
> 6) I then deleted the SDF files  on the client machine.
>
> 7) Once those files were deleted, I re-ran the configuration wizard
>   and it worked perfectly fine.

[or the alternative way is :](http://crmbuilds.blogspot.co.nz/2013/05/rollup-issue-duplicate-value-cannot-be.html)

> 1. Download SQL Server Compact Toolbox for runtime 3.5
>
>    2. Drop table MetadataSchema.EntityClientStatistics,Constraint name = PK__MetadataSchema.EntityClientStatistics__000000000000071C
>    3. Try  again.